# Unable to click an RadioButton with HtmlUnit

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

I'm having a terrible time on HtmlUnit, there's this Frame im into with an TextField, a Button related to the TextField, an RadioButton and another Button. In order to the RadioButton to be clickable i gotta fill the TextField and click for "Search", then click the RadioButton in order to click the last button in the form, which generates an List of contracts. Though it doesn't do so. I have like 99.999% sure that the RadioButton with 2 JS events isn't working, it has both an onMouseDown and an onClick event. I've tried trillions of different methods doing the same things, waited lifetimes for JavaScript with Thread.Sleeps() and waitFor's... Nothing seems to work, the JS events won't work or the RadioButton isn't being actually pressed, i know that because the last Button on the page returns me an error saying its conditions hasn't been fullfiled. Any idea what could be causing the RadioButton to just don't work? Im sure im referring correcly to it, i've tried XPaths, Id's, everything.

Thanks to whoever reads this and try to suggest something.

Comment: Htmlunit is on GitHub. Please open an issue and provide as many details as possible

Comment: Just made it!
https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues/117
Thanks again!